# Error when making a parallel, binary (logistic) regression for a Sparse matrix with glmnet

Tags: r, logistic-regression, glmnet

I want to perform a parallelised logistic ridge-regression with the glmnet package. 
My data is a big sparse matrix (10 million observations and around 60k columns).

I did a small trial for a subset of the data (both observations and column subset) and it worked. The following code would be equivalent to what I am doing:

```
library(Matrix)
library(glmnet)
library(doMC)
#for reproducibility
set.seed(18)
#initialise cores
registerDoMC(cores=2)

sparseMat<-sparseMatrix(i=rep(1:50,4),j=sample(20,200,replace=TRUE),x=rep(1,200))
y<-as.factor(sample(2,50,replace=TRUE))

cvfit<-cv.glmnet(x=sparseMat,y=y,standardize=FALSE,family="binomial",alpha=0,parallel=TRUE)
```

However, when I input the whole matrix the process crashes providing the next error message:

```
Error in max(sapply(outlist, function(obj) min(obj$lambda))) : 
invalid 'type' (list) of argument
```

I am not sure what causes the error and I do not know what the error message is pointing out.

I am using r in an RStudio linux server with 8 cores.

`sessionInfo()`:

```
R version 3.1.2 (2014-10-31)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)

attached base packages:
[1] parallel  stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] doMC_1.3.3      iterators_1.0.7 glmnet_2.0-2    foreach_1.4.2   Matrix_1.1-5
```

UPDATE I:

As I cannot share the data that generates the error (confidentiality issues) and the reproductions I tried generated memory overflows rather than the error shown, I will reformulate the question:

*Is the error message I got memory related or is it related to something else?*

Given the size of the dataset a memory related error is an option. However, the error message points to an internal issue related to having more than one minimum within the lambda values. If it is not a memory issue how shall I proceed, is there a workaround?

Comment: Is your example supposed to work or fail?

Comment: The small example works. What I would like to know why the big one fails.

Comment: Try to provide an example which fails.

Comment: For privacy issues I cannot upload the dataset. I will try to generate a equivalent example, however, what I would like to know is what might be causing the error as the regression works both for a subset of observations (using all the variables) and a subset of variables (using all the observations).

Comment: I also have this error and it is definitely not memory related. I get it only when use parallel cross-validation. When I set `parallel=FALSE` - no problems. Strange bug.

Comment: It has been a while since I got that error but is "good" to know that I was not the only one. glmnet is an excellent package but there may be some strange casuistry in which it fails. I could not disclose the data at that time and I cannot do it now (I switched jobs). If you are able to provide me the dataset that crashes for you, I would be glad to confirm there is a bug. I do not know the steps from there on, but it would be a personal victory to close this post once and for all. Thanks in any case.

Comment: I am facing the same problem with glmnet 2.0-5 when using parallel backend DoParallel. It works fore small dataset, and then fails when the dataset grows.

Comment: @Boris At the time I could not provide a reproducible example, are you able to generate one? If so, I would be happy to try it in a linux OS and a windows OS.

Comment: Hi @JonNagra, yes it is reproductible with a dataset large enough (n>100,000 and p>16,000). My dataset is confidential though. I should try to generate a fake one and see if it crashes similarly.

Comment: I've painfully reproduced this error with the following dataset: https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/bank+marketing using the file `bank-additional/bank-additional-full.csv`. I am using the doParallel backend and like @DmitriySelivanov suggests setting `parallel=FALSE` stops the error from happening. You're not alone!